# Likelihood ratio test between two hypothesis

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, decision-theory

I have two hypothesis as below:

Under $H_1$, $f_x(x) = 3/2 * x^2$ where $x \epsilon (-1,1)$

Under $H_0$,  $f_x(x) =$ Uniformly distributed between $x \epsilon (-1,1)$

What is the maximum likelihood decision rule to maximize the detection where false alarm (given that $H_0$ happened but $H_1$ decided) is less than or equal to 0.1?

How can i solve this?

Regards...

Comment: The notation $H_1 = 3/2*x^2$ makes no sense. If you intended to specify the density function of the null distribution on $(-1,1),$ please try again.

Comment: @BruceET edited

Answer (score 1):

*My interpretation of the Problem:* I suppose you are using a single observation, and testing
$H_0: f_0(x) = .5,$ for $-1 < x < 1$ against $H_1: f_1(x) = \frac 3 2 x^2$ for
$-1 < x < 1,$ at the significance level $\alpha = .1.$ (It is customary
to state $H_0$ first.)

*Main idea:* According to the LR test you want the rejection region to be
where $f_0$ is small relative to $f_1.$ So the rejection region will be
in two parts near $-1$ and $1$ such that, under the density $f_0(x),$
the total probability is $\alpha = .1.$

In the sketch below, you want the probabilities outside the vertical
dotted blue lines and under the density $f_0$ (green) to add to $\alpha = .1.$

[image]

Comment: i can not open the link

Comment: hi again. so the probability that i want to find, which is the  probability of detection, is the area which is outside the vertical dotted blue lines and above the density $f_0$ (green) and below density $f_1$ (red). Am I correct?

Comment: Almost. The (2 parts of) the rejection region should be near $\pm 1.$ The area under the (green) null PDF for the rejection region should be 5% for a test at the 5% level. [The total area of two rectangles should be .05.] Roughly, the rejection region is where the null PDF is low relative to the alternative (red) PDF.

Comment: First you said that: "In the sketch below, you want the probabilities outside the vertical dotted blue lines and under the density f0 (green) to add to α=.1." and now you are saying that " [The total area of two rectangles should be .05.] ". Which one is true? I am confused...

Comment: Both are true. Suggest to read about likelihood-ratio test again, and look at examples in text and notes. Maybe some initial misconceptions need to be abandoned.